# Is there a way to add proactive welcome message in Amazon lex bot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

Is there a way to give a proactive welcome message in Amazon lex bot. So that when ever it is opened it greets the user with that message before user typing anything? want to use this bot in my personal website.

I tried to find a way for the same but didn't find anything. The intention is to give the list of issues bot can help user with in welcome message before user starts typing anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that is possible natively.

In order to achieve this, you would need to invoke your chatbot when the page loads using the `postText()` method with some text that would invoke the intent you're wanting to fire off; presumably a `hello` or `greeting` intent. Remember, to keep track of the state so that you do not trigger the welcome each time the user refreshes the page.

Have a look through this older issue thread for some more detail:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/issues/197